# Sorting arraylist. Comparation by int value

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I'd like to sort my Listview by int value. I've looked in similar questions and solutions and have done something like this but it is not sorting listView descending (nothing happens btw). In arrayList are objects which this object has field named "rating". Here is a code:

```
public class GifModel implements Comparable<GifModel>, Comparator<Integer>{
.......
.......

@Override
    public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lhs.intValue() > rhs.intValue() ? 1:0;
    }

}
```

And in main activity. "ratingSort" is a List:

```
ratingSort = new ArrayList<GifModel>(list);

    Collections.sort(ratingSort, new Comparator<GifModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(GifModel lhs, GifModel rhs) {
        return lhs.compare(lhs.getRating(),rhs.getRating());
        }

        });
```

Comment: @nKn That would yield a syntax error, as `lhs` and `rhs` are not primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sorting comparator to this and you should be good to go:

```
Collections.sort(ratingSort, new Comparator<GifModel>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(GifModel lhs, GifModel rhs) {
        if (lhs.getRating() < rhs.getRating())
            return -1;
        else if (lhs.getRating() > rhs.getRating())
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: You are the best. That's want I need. Thank You :)

Comment: No problem glad to help. Just remember when doing Comparators that you need to return 3 possible values. Your original had only 1 or 0.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for this annotation. I'll remember it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to sort the listview, but the collection which you are adapting to it. You can do a simple `Comparator()` to accomplish so.

Comment: But I must define the tag which will be used in comparation. I can not compare like that

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, it is redundant to make your `GifModel` impl. `Comparator`, if it has already impl. `Comparable<GifModel>`.

You can just implement the `compareTo(GifModel o)` method, and there compare the  `gifModelObj.getRating()` thus you can just `Collections.sort(ratingSort)`

If you had requirements like sorting the list by `any possible field of GifModel`, you can let your `GifModel` implement neither Comparator nor Comparable. And create a number of `Comparators` for the sorting.

Comment: I have one implemented already for sorting by Date and I need another solution

Comment: @Darek if you want to sort the list in 10 different ways (by 10 different fields), you can create 10 comparator, and pass it to `Collections.sort`. you could let your class impl. Comparable, if you want it could be sorted in someway like "default".